# Recently view product slider?

Tags: magento-1.9

I got Recently view product view in home page is it any script for sliding for recent view product? Please suggest some of the script for sliding product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Magento 1.9` they have a slider code. So just copy your file from base folder and place it in your theme.

i.e,

> app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\reports\product_viewed.phtml

copy and put it in

> app\design\frontend\your_package\your_theme\template\reports\product_viewed.phtml

Then add a `class="slideshow-container"` for a parent container. And add `class="slideshow"` for a `ul or ol`.

Like

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<div class="block block-list block-viewed">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Recently Viewed Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content slideshow-container"> <!-- Added a class for parent container-->
        <ol id="recently-viewed-items" class="mini-products-list slideshow"> <!-- Added a class for container-->
        <?php foreach ($_products as $_item): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                    <span class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></span>
                </a>
                <div class="product-details">
                    <p class="product-name">
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                            <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName() , 'name') ?>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('recently-viewed-items');</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Refer this [Link(HOMEPAGE SLIDER)](https://www.creare.co.uk/new-features-magento-ce-1-9-responsive-theme)

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: @Manojkothari You are using magento1.9 right?

Comment: have you use code which i have posted here

Comment: yes i m using 1.9 only. Plz check the url http://totaltoys.com/update

Comment: `skin>frontend>rwd>default>js>slideshow.js` file is missing. If you add that in your page, you'll get slider

Comment: How could I add similar slider in Magento 2 ?

Comment: Can you please suggest same for `magento 2.2`